# Distinguish integer string and boolean in query-string?

Tags: query-string

In HTTP request we may get data from body or query-string. In this topic we will assume JSON is body format.

In JSON we are able to distinguish integer string and boolean parameters.

```
{
  "tata": "test",
  "titi": 123,
  "toto": true
}
```

But is there a way in query-string to distinguish integer string and boolean parameters ?

```
https://example.com/path/to/page?titi=123&toto=true
// titi is integer or string ?
// toto is boolean or string ?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to distinguish from the query string because it's a string, only from a json